# Import Emails without pop3 or smtp or imap

Tags: email, email-client

I have an email account on `mail.in.com`.  However their email service will shut down soon. 

Hence I need to transfer all of these emails (more than 4k) to my `gmail` account.

Is there any **software** or **service** which will allow me to do so ?

Please note that `mail.in.com` does not support `POP3`, `IMAP`, `SMTP` but only web based access; so using gmail's import feature is not a possibility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without an IMAP or POP3 it is not possible to import a remote mailbox automatically using a generic program. However It may be possible to write one that recursively goes through the entire webmail interface to fetch all mails.

But I don't recommend this way though, as in your case your provider gives you the ability to [download](http://mail.in.com/newmail/userinfo.php) your mails as files (As far as I can guess as text or HTML-files) and also to forward the to another account (I don't know what they mean exactly).

To import the downloaded mails as files to an existing IMAP-Account, you can use the Addon [ImportExportTools](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/thunderbird/addon/importexporttools/) for Thunderbird, which can handle various file-formats for imports.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Forward here means that all **new mails** to `mail.in.com` will be automatically forwarded to the new id till March. As they are providing a zip file containing the HTML of the emails, I guess that I need to use thunderbird to merge all those with gmail.

Comment: Perhaps you could use a tool like these  http://www.weirdkid.com/products/emailchemy/ or http://www.aid4mail.com/email-conversionto upload your downloaded email files into another email account via IMAP?

Comment: @ExtremeCoders Yes, there're for example the ImportExportTools (Addon for Thundbird) which can do that.